# Read a JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

My json file is datas.json:

```
{"firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Doe", "age" : "28"}
```

How can I in jQuery, output the datas like this please:
My name is `John Doe` and I have `28` years old.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You put it in a variable. so:

```
mydata = "{"firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Doe", "age" : "28"}";
```

Then you can use it like this:

`mydata.firstname` -> It will output John

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {"firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Doe", "age" : "28"};
alert("My name is " + json.firstname + " " + json.lastname + " and I have " + json.age + " years old.");
```